# Regular expression to allow only one space between words

Tags: asp.net, regex

I've a textbox in an ASP.NET application, for which I need to use a regular expression to validate the user input string. Requirements for regex are -

1. It should allow only one space between words. That is, total number of spaces between words or characters should only be one.
2. It should ignore leading and trailing spaces.

Matches:

- Test
- Test abc

Non Matches:

- Test abc def
- Test        abc  --> I wanted to include multiple spaces between the 2 words. However the editor ignores these extra spaces while posting a question.

Comment: Two different interpretations of your matching criteria suggest that it is unclear - are more than two words allowed?

Comment: I've edited the question for better clarity. Liked you pointed - since the requirement is to disallow more than one space between words, it restricts the user input to contain a maximum of two words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there must be either one or two 'words' (i.e. sequences of non-space characters)

```
"\s*\S+(\s\S+)?\s*"
```

Change `\S` to `[A-Za-z]` if you want to allow only letters.

Comment: Wow, the expression "\s*\w+(\s\w+)?\s*" works prefectly well for the spaces. The only issue I see is, it is not allowing any special characters within the string. I need to allow special characters and numerics as well.

Comment: @Test_User. Edited to allow any non-space characters.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforward:

```
/^ *(\w+ ?)+ *$/
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. It keeps throwing validation error even for a string that didn't have any spaces.

Comment: Check your copy/paste, because it works in refiddle using the .NET RE library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will do?

```
\s*\S+?\s?\S*\s*
```

Edit: Its a server-encoded regex, meaning that you might need to remove one of those escaping slashes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very poor at regular expressions. I'm setting the ValidationExpression property of my RegEx validation control with your expression and it won't match a single word. I would appreciate if you can make any required modifications to the expression and post it. Thank you!

Comment: Updated my post - try again.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^\s*(\w+\s)*\w+\s*$
```