# Regular expression to allow only one hyphen between words

Tags: asp.net, regex

I've a textbox in an ASP.NET application, for which I need to use a regular expression to validate the user input string. Requirement is that total number of hyphens with the string can only be one.

Matches:

1. Test
2. Test-hello
3. Test-
4. -Test

Non Matches:

1. Test--hello
2. -test-
3. test-hello--

Comment: Look like Regular Expression pop quiz in SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527034/regular-expression-to-allow-only-one-space-between-words

Comment: if you could do in the codebehind: myInput.Count(x => x == '-') > 1 ? :) (just kidding of course...)

Comment: :-)...We had custom validators before which did the same, but as part of a migration we are replacing all custom validators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern to match strings with zero or one hyphen:

```
^[^-]*-?[^-]*$
```

**Explanation:**

Starting from the beginning of the string (`^`), it will mach zero or more non-hyphen characters (`[^-]*`), followed by an optional hyphen (`-?`), followed by zero or more non-hyphen characters (`[^-]*`) and the end of the string (`$`)

---

This pattern to match strings with exactly one hyphen:

```
^[^-]*-[^-]*$
```

**Explanation:**

Starting from the beginning of the string (`^`), it will mach zero or more non-hyphen characters (`[^-]*`), followed by a required hyphen (`-`), followed by zero or more non-hyphen characters (`[^-]*`) and the end of the string (`$`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
^[^-]*-?[^-]*$
```

`[^-]` is a non hyphen character.

Comment: Just tested it. the hyphens don't need to be escaped in this case.

Comment: @p.s.w.g : ok :) +1 for you for having tested !